# Simple NT/Algebra Proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $(p-1)(q-1)\ge 1$, over positive reals greater than 1, then $p+q\ge 4$.

In essence, it seems this is proving that if $p+q<pq$, then $p+q\ge 4$, but this doesn't necessarily help.

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

If $xy\ge 1$, then 
$$(x+y)^2=(x-y)^2+4xy\ge 4$$
and therefore $|x+y|\ge 2$.

Let $x=p-1$ and $y=q-1$. We conclude that $p+q-2\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $[\sqrt{p-1}-\sqrt{q-1}]^2 \ge 0$, it follows that $(p-1)+(q-1) \ge 2\sqrt{(p-1)(q-1)}\ge 2$.

Hence $p+q \ge 4$. QED

Answer (score 0):

$p+q < pq$ is simply equivalent to $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} < 1$.

$\frac{p+q}{2} \geq \frac{2}{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}}$ - inequality between arithmetic and harmonic averages.

Hence $(p+q) \cdot ( \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} ) \geq 4 $

So if we would to have $p+q<4$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} < 1$,  we get the contradiction.